# Horizontal Range bar labels showing all the same label

Tags: c#, mysql, charts

I am building a range bar chart in c# connected to a MySQL db. The problem is that all the bars in the chart are showing the same label when they should have different values. I can't figure out why. Should I be creating different Series instead? What am I doing wrong? I researched this but unfortunately, I'm having trouble finding a solution. Here is my code:

```
private void LoadChartData()
    {
        var s = new Series();
        s.ChartType = SeriesChartType.RangeBar;

        chart1.Series.Clear();
        chart1.Series.Add(s);

        s.SetCustomProperty("PixelPointWidth", "25");

        chart1.Series[0].YValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "yyyy-MM-dd";
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Interval = 1;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Days;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.IntervalOffset = 1;

        chart1.Series[0].XValueType = ChartValueType.String;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = minDate.ToOADate();
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = maxDate.ToOADate();



        ConnectionStringSettings conSettings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["shopmanagerConnectionString1"];
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(conSettings.ToString());
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(@"select * from shopmanager.planning;", con);
        MySqlDataReader myReader;
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                //check if machine is "en attente"
                string notPlanned;
                notPlanned = myReader.GetString("machine_name");
                if(notPlanned == "En attente")
                {
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    s.Label = myReader.GetString("project_number") + " " + myReader.GetString("part_name");
                    s.LabelForeColor = Color.Black;
                    s["LabelStyle"] = "Left";


                    var start_date = myReader.GetDateTime("predicted_start_date");
                    var predicted_finish_date = myReader.GetDateTime("predicted_delivery");
                    var machine = myReader.GetString("machine_name");

                    s.Points.AddXY(machine, start_date, predicted_finish_date); 
                }
            }
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        con.Close();

    }
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post an image of what you have? Are the labels the only issue you have? - As it stands you have only one series and set its Label several times, but where would a 2nd label come from or belong to??

Comment: As shown on the image, each machine gets assigned projects. Each project has it's own info. That info is what needs to be displayed in the labels. Labelas are one issue. The other one is that the same machine gets repeated on the left when instead, I would like them to overlap to see if there is a conflict between projects.

Comment: OK; maybe you want to add datapoint.Label? AddXY returns the new point's index; use it to reference the pint and set `s.Points[index].Label = yourInfo`

Comment: Thanks. I don't get the index thing. (Sorry i'm new at this) . I tried `s.Points[0].Label = myReader.GetString("project_number") + " " + myReader.GetString("part_name"); ` but now I only get a label on the Makino 2 machine.

Comment: Try: `int pix = s.Points.AddXY(machine, start_date, predicted_finish_date); s.Points[pix ].Label = myReader.GetString("project_number") + " " + myReader.GetString("part_name");`

Comment: That worked perfectly thanks